# PostgreSQL escape characters when using Excel formula

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, escaping

I'd like to generate a query like this:

```
select id, '=FKERES(B2;'D:\nyunyuka\[kotyog.xlsx]Munka1'!$A:$B;2;0)' as
 excel_formula from table;
```

I learned that I have to escape the `'` character using `E` but it seems not working. I assume that I have to escape all the `\` as well. But It's getting complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question correct. Hope that I did.
You need to add extra single quotes like this:

```
select id, '=FKERES(B2;''D:\nyunyuka[kotyog.xlsx]Munka1''!$A:$B;2;0)' as excel_formula 
from table;
```

So, if there is a single quote `'` in a string in a select clause then you have to add another one `''` to make it work.

Comment: Did it! Sorry for not being clear enough. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Sto Nice ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides doubling the quotes you can use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-syntax-lexical.html) instead.

```
    So use
    select id, $Q$=FKERES(B2;'D:\nyunyuka[kotyog.xlsx]Munka1'!$A:$B;2;0)$Q$ as excel_formula 
    from table;

    Instead of

    select id, '=FKERES(B2;''D:\nyunyuka[kotyog.xlsx]Munka1''!$A:$B;2;0)' as excel_formula 
    from table;
```

Where $Q$ in the above takes the place of the opening and closing quote ('). It is generally not worth it for just a couple instances but for long strings with lots of quotes it can sure comes in handy.